# Cannot fetch results from http request to Google Maps API using IONIC 2 framework

Tags: angular, google-maps, http, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3

I would like to use my provider to make a request to Google Maps API and retrieve some results, but I am having trouble as nothing comes back and I have no idea what I did wrong.
My method on provider that makes a request to google:

```
getClosestMovieTheater(): Observable<Place[]>{
    console.log("started request to google.");
    let t = this.http
    .get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key='MY_API_KEY', { headers: this.getHeaders(), withCredentials: true})
    .map(mapAll);

    return t;
}

private getHeaders(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    return headers;
}
```

I am planing to retrieve the closest movie theater according to my location, but for now I am testing it with google example just to see if it works.
Then there are methods for mapping the result:

```
function toP(r:any): Place{
  let p = <Place>({
    lng: r.results.geometry.location.lng,
    lat: r.results.geometry.location.lat
})

  return p;
}
```

`function mapAll(response:Response): Place[]{
  return response.json().map(toP);
}`

Can anyone please help? Thank you in beforehand.

Comment: Where do you call `getClosestMovieTheater`? Show that code too.

Comment: Actually I found out the issue was because of CORS... the problem is I guess it is being disabled by default for localhost... Do you know any solution for enabling it in Opera browser? thank you

Answer (score 1):

CORS headers are set at Google servers, so there is nothing you can do. You should use a places library of Maps JavaScript API instead of the web service calls in client side code.

Take a look at the following documentation that describes Places library of Maps JavaScript API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

The Places library also provides search functionality similar to web services.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for response. I actually just installed Firefox browser and installed extension that enables CORS for localhost and the thing started working :)